# Increase resolution ggplot charts

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using this code:

```
 ggplot(BP, aes(x=1, y=Enrichment_Score, fill=GO.ID)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    coord_polar(theta='y') +
    guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes=list(colour=NA), nrow=6)) +
    theme(axis.ticks=element_blank(), axis.title=element_blank(), axis.text=element_blank(), panel.grid  = element_blank(), legend.position="bottom") +
    ggtitle("Biological Processes")
```

[image]

I'd like to increase the resolution and, thus, the quality of this plot... How might I do this?

Comment: The resolution is controlled by the graphics device that created the saved image. What command/procedure did you use?

Comment: `Export-->save image` in Rstudio

Comment: `ggsave` has a `dpi` parameter. Various functions in the `Cairo` pkg (e.g. `CairoPNG`) have `res` & `dpi` parameters. You'll get better resolution saving to them vs displaying on screen. You can even output to SVG (if your audience can display SVGs) for optimal viewing.

Comment: also, pie charts are evil :-)

Comment: Then you can increase the pixel count (for PNG) or DPI setting (for PDF), or use a vector format (SVG).

Comment: For example... when exporting to PDF it looks beautiful...