# Making pie chart's contours smoother on Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

I am trying to have a nice looking plot for two (or possibly more) continuous values in the form of a pie chart using `ggplot2`.
The code is the following :

```
library("ggplot2")
library("ggthemes") ## for theme_economist
df <- data.frame(origin=c('with','without'),value=c(24536,50456))  
pie <- ggplot(df, aes(x = "",y=value, fill = origin))+  
    geom_bar(width = 1,stat="identity")+  
    coord_polar(theta = "y",start=pi/3)+  
    theme_economist()
```

[image: pie]
The pie is relatively fine except that the contours of the pie seems to be a bit irregularly drawn.Of course when you export it as a pdf it looks fine but displayed in RStudio or Shiny it doesn't look nice at all.
Is there a way to change the resolution of the ggplot object directly or to make `renderplot()` aware that we want to display the image at a high resolution ?
I tried modifying the `res` argument of the `renderPlot()` function but it distorts the image and do not get rid of the irregularity of the border.

How to make the contours of the pie smoother on Shiny or RStudio directly ? Thanks.

Comment: I edited my question to make it to the point and specific

Comment: can you please post/link to an actual image? When I run your code I get [a pretty smooth-looking plot](http://imgur.com/MTyMvX4).  What output are you looking at, with what resolution?

Comment: I put the image I dont know why it does not look as good as yours

Comment: I am displaying that directly into a shiny app is there a way to simply change the resolution of a ggplot ?

Comment: With you mentionning the resolution I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26367013/increase-resolution-ggplot-charts which seems to be basically the same question so it depends on the output do you know a way to display it with high resolution when you use `renderPlot()` in Shiny ?

Comment: The result after exporting it as a pdf is fine ! But I want to change the resolution before that.

Comment: Is there a simpler way than to export is as a pdf and then to render it as an image in Shiny

Comment: Can you add this stuff to your question and make a reproducible example?  The answer *might* be to change the default `res=72` argument to `renderPlot()` ... (but see "Note that this affects the resolution of  PNG rendering in R; it won't change the actual ppi of the
browser.").  I think with appropriate context/reproducible example this could turn into a good question ...

Comment: The ggplot code doesn't really matter, it's the `renderPlot()` code that is determining the resolution and size of the image. Add *that* code (show what you have!), and I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: Actually you are right but I did not realize before Ben Bolker's comment that it was a shiny issue and not a ggplot one. I solved my problem so you can either close the question or answer it I set the `res` argument of `renderPlot()` to its default value of 72 and it is perfectly smooth now !!! (increasing this value more distorts the plot).

Comment: If you've solved your own problem, the best thing to do would be to post your own answer -- this is encouraged

Comment: I cannot answer it as long as it is on hold !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To improve the resolution of the plot on Shiny you have to set the `res` argument to its default value of 72. It does not make a lot of sense to me but it worked just fine the resolution went from really bad to really nice !
However increasing its value further can lead to distortion of the image.
It seems that for now you cannot change the resolution of the plotting object itself before exporting it or rendering it into Shiny.